# Does the U.S. have the right to pressure Asian and European countries to not use Huawei equipments?

Tags: international-relations, international-law, wto

Does the U.S. have the right to pressure Asian and European countries to not use Huawei equipment? Is that against WTO rules? I thought the national security clause only applied within a country's own jurisdiction, but the U.S. is trying to put pressure on other countries? Is this allowed under WTO rules?

Comment: This shouldn't be considered in light of the WTO, but rather in light of the NATO as such pressure is a direct act of war, potentially even a war crime depending on the pressure given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be wrong, but the WTO treaties probably don't have anything to say about foreign policy demands toward third parties. If those countries that the US asks to do this and that take measures that are contrary to WTO treaties, then surely the aggrieved party (e.g. China) can start WTO cases against those countries.

As far as I know, insofar China hasn't started anything at WTO against the US regarding Huawei, and the US almost certainly has taken the most restrictive measures against Huawei (compared to other countries).